# Behaviour of Vue-observable, when adding properties after creation

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'd like to have a little registry in one of my Vue files and decided to use the Vue.observable function Vue provides (yes I could use Vuex, but first I want to try without). Now, when I add properties to my registry after creation (using Vue.set of course), I find that the reactivity of my properties is hard to predict:

1. This does work as expected:

```
const state = Vue.observable({fromObservable: ''})
...
computed:
  fromObservable: () => state.fromObservable
...
In mounted:
  state.fromObservable = 'Success'
```

2. This sadly does not work. Why?

```
const state = Vue.observable({})
...
computed:
  fromObservable: () => state.fromObservable
...
In mounted:
  Vue.set(state, 'fromObservable', 'Success')
```

3. Nested properties work as expected:

```
const state = Vue.observable({values: {}})
...
computed:
  fromObservable: () => state.values.fromObservable
...
In mounted:
  Vue.set(state.values, 'fromObservable', 'Success')
```

4. It does not work, if I instantly assign values to a variable. I have no clue, how this is happening:

```
const state = Vue.observable({values: {}}).values
...
computed:
  fromObservable: () => state.fromObservable
...
In mounted:
  Vue.set(state, 'fromObservable', 'Success')
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mdr4hu8p/) demonstrating this.

Please explain to me, how this can be understood, especially case 2 and 4. Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, Vue2 makes objects reactive using [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

It's safe to say that **not object itself is reactive, it's properties are**

Second important fact is that computed properties:

1. Track reactive dependencies while evaluating

   - dependency is any reactive **property** accessed during function evaluation
2. cache the value and doesn't recompute unless some reactive dependency has changed

### Case 2

- when computed is called, `fromObservable` property of `state` does not exist
- computed returns `undefined`
- not a single getter was accessed!! So list of dependencies which should trigger the recompute is empty (in other words, this computed will never re-evalute again)

### Case 3

- `state.values` getter is accessed in computed property so it's a dependency
- when `Vue.set` is called with `state.values` as an argument, it sees `values` is reactive property (has setter and getter added by Vue) so it registers addition of new property into object it's holding like a change
- as a result, computed property will re-evaluate on next render

### Case 4

- almost like Case 2 because inside computed property, no getter is accessed and returned value is `undefined`
- only time getter is accessed is in `const state = Vue.observable({values: {}}).values` (and returns empty object which is **not reactive by itself**)
- from perspective of Vue, this computed property is constant because it has no reactive dependencies

Luckily for all of us, all this reactivity caveats are fixed in Vue 3 thanks to reactivity system rewritten using [proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) - [here](https://jsfiddle.net/MichalLevy/y2pnw1vr/) is your code rewritten to use Vue 3 - with all cases working!